# Cleaning a Sieve

Tags: equipment, cleaning

Is there a better way of cleaning a sieve, other than stabbing at it with a brush, in a manner such as [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Clean-a-Sieve) ?

I can't help but think there must be....

Comment: It's really to get the scummy bits of 'rice juice' from a sieve, and that kind of thing.

Comment: This question made it onto the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) as an example of a "weak question".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could get yourself a specialized [sieve brush](http://www.globalgilson.com/productDisplay.asp?model=TSA-170) - the things are meant for mining sieves but cooking sieves are generally the same size (0.5mm - 1.0mm, the latter being the [no. 16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_%28scale%29#Sieve_sizing_and_conversion_charts) that the first link is talking about).  I haven't seen any of these sitting in home kitchens - could be that they aren't effective on cooking sieves, but more likely, cooks just don't know or care that they exist.

For the truly dedicated, you could get yourself a [studded sieve cleaner](http://www.filip-gmbh.com/en/noppensiebreiniger.htm) or the similar triangle kind with [brushes](http://www.filip-gmbh.com/en/siebreinigungsbuersten.htm).  These are meant for cleaning *really* fine sieves, as in flour mill equipment, so whether or not it would be useful to you depends on what kind (mesh density) of sieve you have.

Or, if you could loads of money to blow, you could go all out and get yourself an [ultrasonic sieve cleaner](http://www.tovatech.com/ultrasonic-cleaner/applications/ultrasonic-seive-cleaner.php).  Of course, we're now talking about products that don't even *have* a list price, so if you have to ask, you can't afford it.

Here's perhaps the most interesting option for those of you at home, though: I noticed companies out there selling [rubber balls](http://www.mill-industry.com/Rubber%20Ball.html) as sieve cleaners, so I was curious whether or not one could just use an ordinary rubber ball.  I happened to have one of those big squishy stress-reliever balls sitting around and gave it a shot on my 8" sieve/strainer that had some sediment stuck on it - and guess what, it works!  It's not perfect, it didn't get every last grain out, but I only had to rub the inside a couple of times with the ball to get out the vast majority of "dirt".  So there's your "home remedy" for cooks on the cheap.

Comment: man, that is some serious sieve cleaning information.

Comment: what about us lazy guys ? there must be a hack hrmm...

Comment: Wow, an Ultrasonic Sieve Cleaner! Great information, many thanks!

Comment: @Reno: If you're lazy and rich, get the ultrasonic.  If you're just lazy, the rubber ball is really pretty easy.

Answer (score 5):

I've never found this to be a big problem. If I have something dry in there, I give it a few whacks on the divider in my sink, then run it under hot water and scrub with a sponge for a minute. If there is something really stuck on, I might soak it in hot water first. Or if I have room, I'll throw them in the dishwasher. What do you have on your sieve that is giving you particular trouble?

Comment: I was going to answer that I also have no problems, but thought I was missing something obvious :) If I've used my sieve in conjunction with cheesecloth for something liquid, I just make sure to rinse it immediately so nothing dries on it.  If something did dry on it, I'll soak it in a bowl of water (similar to soaking my dishes in a sink) for a few minutes, and it rinses right off.

Comment: FWIW, it's usually dishwasher for me too, but every so often I get a build-up, usually after a few instances of trying to pass through something thick and/or heavily seasoned (salt/pepper/spice grains).